# procmail don't execute php script

Tags: php, freebsd, zend-framework, procmail

I have setup a kannel SMS gateway on my FreeBSD 7.2 - the service works great.

I'm now trying to setup a email2sms feature. For this i have created a system user called `kannel` and all mails are forwarded to this user.

In the home dir of `kannel` i have the following files.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 kannel  kannel    81B 17 jan 09:50 .procmailrc
lrwxr-x---  1 root    kannel    58B 14 jan 13:24 email2sms.php @ -> some-what-some-where
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root    kannel   5,8K 17 jan 09:52 log.email2sms
-rw-------  1 kannel  kannel   1,3K 17 jan 09:50 procmail.log
-rw-r-----  1 root    kannel   606B 14 jan 13:28 rawmail.txt
```

The file `email2sms.php` is a symlink to the a php script (ZendFramework Application) that takes the email from `STDIN`, and uses ZendFramework to parse that mail into an object. It then do a http request to the SMS gateway. The php-script works.

Content of `.procmailrc`

```
LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log
VERBOSE=yes

:0
| php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms
```

From last sent email i have this in `procmail.log`

```
procmail: [97744] Mon Jan 17 09:50:40 2011
procmail: [97744] Mon Jan 17 09:50:40 2011
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER= php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms"
procmail: Executing " php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms"
procmail: Notified comsat: "kannel@:/home/user/kannel/ php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms"
From my@email.tld  Mon Jan 17 09:50:40 2011
 Subject: asdf as
  Folder:  php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms                              2600
```

But there is no new output to log.email2sms, and the script should output the subject of the email.

If i `sudo` as the `kannel` user and pipe a file with raw email to the script, it executes just fine.

```
[root@webserver /home/user/kannel]# /home/user/kannel/ sudo -u kannel cat rawmail.txt | php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms
```

And the command outputs to `log.email2sms` as desired.

Any ideas guys?

**UPDATE**

I changed the phpscript to just `die('bail me out scotty');` and the script executes from .procmail when sending an email. The file `log.email2sms`is appended with the bail text.

So perhaps the content of the mail is not corectly piped over or the Zend Framework class that handles the piped data from STDIN is buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with procmail, but in the Zend Framework script i had.

In ZendFramework, reading email from STDIN use:

```
// will use file_get_contents()
$email = new Zend_Mail_Message(array('file' => "php://stdin"));
```

And NOT:

```
// will use stream_get_contents()
$email = new Zend_Mail_Message(array('file' => "STDIN"));
```

Note to self: Don't use [tips'n'trix given in comments](http://www.techfounder.net/2008/07/18/handling-mail-and-mime-in-php-using-the-zend-framework/#comment-83042909)

Comment: BTW: `kannel` user needs to have a login, i had mine set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a limited shell problem, make sure the php command is in the path, also in order to debug procmail you can always add at top of the file

```
LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log
VERBOSE=on
```

Comment: Already have those lines :) And i have also tried with full path to php in the `.procmailrc` file. What i don't understand, i can succesfully `sudo` the same command line as `kannel`.

Comment: Then you can try redirecting stderr to a file as well and see if that shows something up. php email2sms.php >> log.email2sms 2> error.log

Comment: Nothing goes into to error.log

Comment: Did you actually mean `2> error.log` notice the 2 - is this correct?

Comment: Look at my update in question.